# Does the subspace / quotient of a simply connected space always be simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, quotient-spaces, path-connected

this is a topology question :

> True or false and justify:
>
> > 1) the subspace of a simply connected space is simply connected
> >
> > 2) the quotient of a simply connected space is simply connected

---

My thoughts:

1) False. Consider X = $R^2$ and Y = $S^1 \subseteq $ X. Then X is connected since $R^2$ is convex and any convex space is connected. We know that $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ and for a connected subspace $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\pi_1( \mathbb{Z}$) = {0}. Then $S^1$ is not simply connected. So the statement is false.

2) Not sure how to do this. I tried the X = $R$ and Y = $Z$ and have X/Y $\cong$ $S^1$, which is path connected and therefore simply connected.

Could you check whether my part 1) is correct, and help me with 2）？

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quotient $[0,1]$ by identifying $\{0,1\}$. The quotient that you mentioned also shows it. You already said $S^1$ is not simply connected in your argument for part (1).

Comment: @totoro Thank you! I didn't see that, guess my brain is not functioning well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part 1 is OK. For an even simpler example, you can even consider $\{0,1\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. The line $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and simply connected, but the two-elements set $\{0,1\}$ is not even connected, let alone simply connected.

Your part 2 is good too. The group $\mathbb{R}$ is simply connected, and its quotient by the group $\mathbb{Z}$ is the circle (which is a particular case of a topological quotient), which is not simply connected.

Comment: Thank you for the super fast response! I think your example given for part 1 is much simpler.